# How to stop the result in solr, when phrase containing a stopword?

Tags: search, solr, tokenize, stop-words

I have a problem while searching with Solr a phrase which has stopwords. Solr send result with stopword and this is not my expected output.

I added a word "test" in `stopwords.txt` file.
In `schema.xml` file, I have the field like

```
<field name="searchword" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"   />
```

I indexed some data, then tried to search in solr browser window as follows: **searchword:"test"** and I didn't get result. 
Then again I gave a phrase like **searchword:"test data"** and I got the result. How to avoid such scenario? If it contains stop word Solr should not give any result. How to stop the result in solr, when phrase containing a stopword?

The following is the fieldType I'm using:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">         
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" type="phrase"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I need solution for Solr doesn't provided any result while I give phrase that contains the stopword (test)

Comment: Could you post your schema.xml?

Answer (score 1):

A "stop" word is a word that is not taken into account in a search; it is not a word that "stops" or invalidates results. So the behaviour that you explain is correct: that is what stop words are supposed to do.

There is no way I know of in SOLR to "stop" the results form coming back whenever you use a particular word (maybe someone has an idea?).

The only thing I can think of is:
 - Don't send the query to SOLR when you observe those terms in the query :)
 - Remove the terms from the documents before you index them (e.g. using an UpdateRequestProcessor) and use AND queries, that way whenever a term not indexed appears in the query you will get zero results